# Next.js throws 404 in IIS production

Tags: iis, next.js, web-config, mime-types, next.js13

I set up a new Next.js application (without changing anything) with a custom server and uploaded the built project to IIS. It works locally using `npm run start`, but on IIS, it throws the following errors:
`Refused to execute script from 'https://server_name/_next/static/chunks/webpack-12345asdf.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`
`Refused to execute script from 'https://server_name/_next/static/chunks/framework-12345asdf.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`
`Refused to execute script from 'https://server_name/_next/static/chunks/main-7477d36a73a3487c.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`
And the same for the _app.js, _error.js, buildManifest.js and ssgManifest.js files.

I haven't changed any generated files, like next.config.js or anything in the pages directory, and I'm not using the experimental app directory.

Here is my server.js file, that is in the root directory:

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
            const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

            if (pathname === '/a') {
                await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
            } else if (pathname === '/b') {
                await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
            } else {
                await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
            res.statusCode = 500
            res.end('internal server error')
        }
    })
        .once('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        })
        .listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
        })
})
```

And here is my web.config, also in the root directory:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="static assets" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="([\S]+[.]((html?)|(svg)|(js)|(css)|(png)|(gif)|(jpe?g)|(json)))" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="reactRouter routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.html" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="module" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="modules/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="node_module" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="node_modules/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="public" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="public/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="files" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="files/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="sendToNode">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        <iisnode node_env="production" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".ico" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".svg" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've looked into every documentation and tutorial, that I could find online, but got no solution.

Comment: The official guide doesn't even refer to IIS, https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment, so why bother yourself? The guide you followed must be very old and iisnode is now out of maintenance. You might try to use HttpPlatformHandler which does less miserable things, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ But again, Docker is far better an option.

Comment: Turn out you just need to ask HttpPlatformHandler to call `next start`, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs Simpler `web.config` and no need of `server.js`.

Answer (score -1):

This is an IIS issue.

I'm surprised in 2023 since I first encountered this in 1998!

Anyway.

Somewhere in the IIS controls there is a place to do MIME type mappings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

The link above may work for your version of IIS of you may have to hunt around.

Historically I think this is because MS relied far more on file name extensions for types.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but the MIME types seem to be correct. I have almost everything included (js - application/javascript, json - application/json, css - text/css).
I'm starting to believe it has something to do with the web.config, but no idea.

Comment: if you use the inspector in your browser to look at the headers on those files what does it show? If I look at the content type for one of the _next/static/chunks/webpack....js files on one of my published sites I see `content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Anything like that can be categorized as an "IIS issue". But all requests are passed to iisnode, so little to do with IIS itself. Clearly Node.js wasn't there in 1998.

Comment: For me, they are `text/html` types on IIS. Running the app locally with `npm run start` it loads perfectly and the types are correctly `application/javascript; charset=UTF-8`. I'm not sure if the type error or the 404 error comes first.

Comment: So configure your IIS to serve the correct mime types.

Comment: also you don't say whether you are using iisnode or the reverse proxy setup. Reverse proxy would be your best bet.